# Can i use Double type in PlutoGrid?

Tags: flutter, datatable, datatables, datagrid, flutter-dependencies

i'm trying to develop an flutter application with [PlutoGrid](https://pub.dev/packages/pluto_grid) packegae.
I need to enter Double values in columns that type is PlutoColumnType.number(). but the PlutoGrid don't let to enter float value.
Is there any configuration needed to work with float numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The format of number value is configurable with format parameter as below:

```
    PlutoColumn(
    title: 'weight',
    field: 'weight',
    type: PlutoColumnType.number(format: "###.###"),
    enableEditingMode: true,
    width: 100),
```

it enable user to input the values like 545.330